# Adding a Skype meeting invite through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to send a Skype meeting invite through excel macros. Is there a way to do it? Currently I can only create a normal meeting invite.

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application

Dim ol_Meeting As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

Set ol_Meeting = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentitem)
ol_Meeting.MeetingStatus = olMeeting

With ol_Meeting

  .Display
  .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

End With
```

Comment: Skype meeting is outlook add-in. and doesnt follow object model. I think this can be possible via `Send key` method. send Alt key shortcuts like in this case `Alt` `H` `PM`

Comment: You can also use Microsoft UI Automation to locate the element and simulate a click too. This might be a bit more reliable than sendkeys.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I think adding links without using the Skype controls means you lose the "join online meeting" in the meeting reminders.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23697130)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Skype for Business and assume the macro is for you to use you can just create an outlook meeting invite and adding the automatic Skype link, right click on skype meeting link, edit hyperlink, copy it and add to your macro's email body.

This will populate your email with the link to access any Skype Meeting that you usually send. It works for me.